# Binding data context to view using DesignInstance

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, mvvm

In my solution there is one project with 2 folders: ViewModels and Views. ViewModels folder consists of MainViewModel file and 3 folders with other viewmodels, let them be VM1, VM2 and VM3. Views folder consists of MainView file and 3 folders with other views, let them be V1, V2 and V3.

The idea is to put TabControl with 3 tab items with each view on MainView.

I have some problems with namespaces:

VM1:

```
namespace UPR.ViewModels
{
    public class VM1
    {
        public VM1()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

V1.xaml.cs:

```
namespace UPR.Views
{
    public partial class V1 : UserControl
    {
        public V1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

}
```

V1.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UPR.Views.V1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:UPR.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
         DataContext="{d:DesignInstance ViewModels:VM1}">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel></StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MainView.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UPR.Views.MainView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:UPR.Views"
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:UPR.ViewModels"
         xmlns:dx="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/core" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         DataContext="{d:DesignInstance ViewModels:MainViewModel}">

<Grid>
    <dx:DXTabControl Grid.Row="0">
        <dx:DXTabItem x:Name="xV1Tab">
            <dx:DXTabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="V1 tab" FontSize="14"/>
            </dx:DXTabItem.Header>
            <Views:MonitoringView DataContext="{Binding V1Content}"/>
        </dx:DXTabItem>

        <dx:DXTabItem x:Name="xV2Tab">
            <dx:DXTabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="V2 tab" FontSize="14"/>
            </dx:DXTabItem.Header>
            <Views:DetailsView DataContext="{Binding V2Content}"/>
        </dx:DXTabItem>

        <dx:DXTabItem x:Name="xV3Tab">
            <dx:DXTabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="V3 tab" FontSize="14"/>
            </dx:DXTabItem.Header>
            <Views:NewTasksView DataContext="{Binding V3Content}"/>
        </dx:DXTabItem>
    </dx:DXTabControl>
</Grid>
```

The project doesn't even compile because of two kinds of errors:

1 - VM1 doesn't exist in namespace "clr-namespace:ViewModels"

2 - tag "DesignInstance" doesn't exist in namespace XML "http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"

These errors are for other views and viewmodels(VM2, VM3, V2, V3, MainVM, MainV), too.

Seems like it's a lag. Because when I write "ViewModels:" - IntelliSense offers me list of viewmodels by that path. When I write "d:" IntelliSense offers me to write "d:DesignInstance".

Any ideas, how to solve this? May be I should do something with namespaces or project structure?

Comment: Try to use `d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance ViewModels:VM1}"`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, Oh, thank you, my bad) You can answer this, I will mark as an Answer.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the comment, sometimes one doesn't want the data to load in design time, then use `IsDesignTimeCreatable` as needed:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:Episode, d:IsDesignTimeCreatable=False}"
```

Othertimes one may have mock data which one wants to hook up, then setup static data:

```
d:DataContext="{x:Static local:MockDataSource.VM1}"
```